# express delivery service (overnight)

Tags: meaning

> $18 for Express Delivery Service(overnight)

Does the *overnight* here mean they will delivery the package on next business day?

or

It means the package will be delivered at night?

Answer (score 9):

It means that the package will be delivered on the next business day.

In this context, "overnight" means that the package will be in transit overnight; however, you will receive the package at your normal delivery time the next day.

Comment: That's it. It doesn't mean they will ring the doorbell at 2 AM to deliver the package. `;)`

Answer (score 1):

*It means the package will be delivered at night?* - I'm just adding that **that is also possible.**

I upvoted Daniel and that's the answer. But then to add a value to this question I'm answering it separately.

Ditto what Daniel says that in **that context,** overnight means the package will be in transit overnight. However, you receive it at your doorstep in normal hours.

**However,** there are some courier services/companies that offer deliveries **at midnight** as well. This is an add-on services to attract people who want their goods to be deliver at exact time and this **could be midnight!**. But I should mention that they call this special delivery as **midnight delivery** or terms the like.

Such gifts are surprise gifts and are common when you want to wish your loved ones on their birthday, sharp at midnight when their day has begun. Personally, I love that ;)

[One of such service providers is here.](http://www.bahraingreetings.com/cmspage.php?page_id=51) They deliver their goods at 11:59 pm, a minute short though.